# Change delimiter in string type of variable in bash

Tags: bash, shell, while-loop, sh

I have small task.

I should write:

```
data="duke,rock,hulk,donovan,john"
```

And in the next variable, i should change delimiter of first variable.

```
data2="duke|rock|hulk|donovan|john"
```

What is the correct way to do this on bash ?

This is a small part of script, what i should do.

For example, i use construction "WHILE-GETOPS-CASE" to use usernames in parameter for excluding them.

```
ls /home/ | egrep -v $data2
```

Comment: You want `egrep -v "$data2"` to prevent the shell from performing wildcard expansion or whitespace tokenization on the value.

Comment: Don't parse the output of `ls`. If you need files not matching a pattern, use extended patterns. `ls /home/!(duke|rock|hulk|donovan|john)`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can easily replace a single character with an expansion:

```
data="duke,rock,hulk,donovan,john"
data2=${data//,/|}
echo "$data2"
```

Breaking down the syntax:

- `${data` means "expand based on the value found in variable `data`;
- `//` means "search all occurences of";
- The lone `/` means "replace with what follows".

Note that some characters may need to be escaped, but not the comma and vertical bar.

Then you may filter the results like this:

```
ls /home/ | egrep -v "$data2"
```

Answer (score 3):

Another very similar way would be to use `tr` (translate or delete characters):

```
data="duke,rock,hulk,donovan,john"
data2=$(echo $data | tr ',' '|')
echo "$data2"
```

Comment: I think this is cleaner!